# How to make my scripts work on my components in next.js?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass, next.js

I have a problem with my script, I am using next and React in my pages / _app.js file I have the following code:

```js
import axios from "axios";
import { $ } from "jquery";
import App from "next/app";
import Router from "next/router";
import { destroyCookie, parseCookies } from "nookies";

import Layout from "../components/_App/Layout";
import "../public/css/boot.css";
import "../public/css/icons.css";
import "../public/css/themes/style.css";
import "../public/jquery";
import "../public/scripts";
import baseUrl from "../utils/baseUrl";

class MyApp extends App {
    static async getInitialProps({ Component, ctx }) {
        const { token } = parseCookies(ctx);

        let pageProps = {};

        if (Component.getInitialProps) {
            pageProps = await Component.getInitialProps(ctx);
        }

        if (!token) {
            const isProtectedRoute =
                ctx.pathname === "/profile" ||
                ctx.pathname === "/admin/add-product" ||
                ctx.pathname === "/my-orders-history" ||
                ctx.pathname === "/admin/users" ||
                ctx.pathname === "/admin/dashboard";
            if (isProtectedRoute) {
                redirectUser(ctx, "/auth/login");
            }
        } else {
            try {
                const payload = { headers: { Authorization: token } };
                const url = `${baseUrl}/api/account`;
                const response = await axios.get(url, payload);
                const user = response.data;
                const isRoot = user.role == "root";
                const isAdmin = user.role == "admin";
                // if authenticated but not root or admin
                const isNotPermitted =
                    !(isRoot || isAdmin) &&
                    (ctx.pathname === "/admin/add-product" ||
                        ctx.pathname === "/admin/customers" ||
                        ctx.pathname === "/admin/orders" ||
                        ctx.pathname === "/admin/dashboard");
                if (isNotPermitted) {
                    redirectUser(ctx, "/products");
                }
                pageProps.user = user;
            } catch (error) {
                // console.error("Error getting current user", error);
                //invalid token
                destroyCookie(ctx, "token");
                redirectUser(ctx, "/auth/login");
            }
        }

        return { pageProps };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener("storage", this.syncLogout);
        require($)(window);
    }

    syncLogout = e => {
        if (e.key === "logout") {
            Router.push("/");
        }
    };

    render() {
        const { Component, pageProps } = this.props;
        return (
            <Layout {...pageProps}>
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </Layout>
        );
    }
}

export default MyApp;
```

In my components/_App/Layouts.js tenho o seguinte codigo:

```js
import React from "react";

import Head from "next/head";

import Footer from "./Footer";
import StaticHeader from "./StaticHeader";

const Layout = ({ children, user }) => {
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Head>
                <meta charset="UTF-8" />
                <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
                <title>WdpShoes | Home</title>

                <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" />
                <link
                    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Open+Sans:wght@400;700;800&display=swap"
                    rel="stylesheet"
                />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="./public/css/icons.css" />
                <link href="https://file.myfontastic.com/gMNiHf8HU5GG4r6y622k2N/icons.css" rel="stylesheet" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/boot.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/themes/style.css" />
                <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/css/themes/logo/favicon.png" />
                <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
            </Head>
            <body>
                <StaticHeader user={user} />
                {children}
                <Footer />
                <script src="/jquery.js"></script>
                <script src="/scripts.js"></script>
                <script src="/css/themes/script.js"></script>
            </body>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default Layout;
```

In the Components that are in my Layout the jquery and javascript are working but in my components they are not
When I import my script into my pages / _app.js file I encounter the following error:

> ReferenceError: $ is not defined
> at Object../public/scripts.js (C:\Users\walter\Desktop\mystore.next\server\pages_app.js:5217:1)

I looked for some materials and I didn't find anything that could help me solve this problem that is preventing me from developing several projects

I know the purpose of the site is to answer questions but to better explain my problem I have the complete code at:
https://codesandbox.io/s/dawn-mountain-vme5e?file=/pages/_app.js

And in its current state it encounters the Internal Server Error due to the fact that the $ function is returning an undefined,Because my script and jquery are not working correctly in my components

Answer (score 1):

To understand your issue, a little theory is needed. Next.js uses  [server-side rendering](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#server-side-rendering) and [static generation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/pages#static-generation-recommended), which means the all code is initially run **on the server**. jQuery is a **client-side** library and it can't run on the server. Therefore, you need to ensure that all the jQuery code is executed only on the client side. You can do this by checking if the `window` object exists and only then executing jQuery. Also, you've forgotten to `include` jQuery in your `scripts.js` file.

Modify the
`scripts.js` file:

```js
import $ from "jquery";

if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
  $(function () {
    // Rest of the code...
  }
}
```

Next, modify the `componentDidMount` function in `_app.js`:

```js
componentDidMount() {
  window.addEventListener("storage", this.syncLogout);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much thanks to you I managed to continue my project